# Inherits does not propose auto correction

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have created a form, and I want it to inherit from a certain custom form.

Before I updated from Win 7 to Win 10, an autocorrection was proposed.

But now VS2015 RC does not propose such a correction to me.

My code is:

```
 Public Class frmFavoriteURLs : Inherits tCustomForm
```

The error is:
The frmFavoriteURLs class may not be different to the form's base class partial types.

Can somebody tell me how to activate the auto correction again or tell me how to correct the problem manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the form's frmFavoriteURLs.Designer.vb code to

```
Partial Class frmFavoriteURLs
    Inherits tws.tCustomForm
```

But I wonder why VS2015 RC on Win 10 does not propose this correction automatically.